# Decarboxylation of alpha-amino acids to amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

In this reaction, what are the ideal circumstances?
[image: ttt]

1. Which base would be a great choice?
2. How much time does it take for tryptophan to fully decarboxylate?
3. What is the ideal temperature for this type of reaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just heating with base is ineffective.
Laval and Golding [[1](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2003-37512)] describe a general procedure for the decarboxylation of α-amino acids using *N*-bromosuccinimide and Ni(0) in aqueous solution. The yields are pretty good.

#### Reference

1. Laval, G.; Golding, B. T. One-Pot Sequence for the Decarboxylation of α-Amino Acids. *Synlett* **2003**, No. 4, 0542–0546. DOI: [10.1055/s-2003-37512](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2003-37512).

Comment: Thank you, btw heating with base why doesn't effective? What would happen to tryptophan?

Comment: I think you would just get a very hot soln of the sodium salt of tryptophan.

Comment: I added a complete reference; however, it doesn't look like authors mention Ni(0) at all, instead they used nickel(II) dichloride hexahydrate. IMO it would be beneficial for others if there were a bit more details from the paper itself, including reaction schemes and the reported yields (authors give exact numbers for each reaction, not just "*pretty good*"). Otherwise it leaves an impression that the paper haven't been read beyond the abstract.

Comment: The authors use Nickel(II) Chloride plus sodium borohydride which generates Ni(0) in situ

Comment: The reaction of Laval is two steps. NBS effects oxidative decarboxylation and oxidation of the resultant imine to a nitrile. NiCl2/NaBH4  effects reduction of the nitrile to an amine.